# Checkout... vs. Check out as Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

If I want to check out a Maven project in Eclipse (from SVN), I have two options

- Checkout...
- Check out as Maven project...

In the second option, there is probably some magic from the m2e subclipse connector involved, but what is exactly the difference? What should I go for?